# SignatureDoesNotMatch For PresignedURL in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

```
public S3PresignedURLServiceImpl() {
        amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withRegion(S3PresignedURLConstants.DEFAULT_REGION)
                .build();
    }
```

[In local it is working but when lambda is deployed on the console getting

> SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

```
try {
    // Set the pre-signed URL to expire after specified time.
    java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
    if(data.getExpiryTime() > 0) {
        expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * data.getExpiryTime();
    } else {
        expTimeMillis += 100 * 60 * 60 * 6;
    }
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);
    HttpMethod httpMethod = data.isUpload()?HttpMethod.PUT:HttpMethod.GET;

    Logger.logInfo("Generating pre-signed URL.",REPORTER);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(data.getBucketName(), data.getFilePath())
            .withMethod(httpMethod)
            .withExpiration(expiration);
    if(!data.isUpload())
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.withVersionId(data.getVersionId());
    else generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType(data.getContentType());

    url = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
    responseData.setPreSignedUrl(url.toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new S3PresignedURLException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: We should first narrow down the problem: since this code does both upload and download, which one isn't working?   Also, you are saying there is an error in the Lambda console... but the code you have shown is only *generating* the URL -- not actually trying to use it. When does this error occur?

Comment: I am working on only upload presignedUrl. here lambda is attached to api gateway . I am using this presign url in my angular application to upload file into s3. I trying to upload by using signed Url  it return 403 error code message "SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
If i run my lambda local machine it return signedUrl i can able to uplaod file by using this localy generated signed url.

Answer (score 0):

Please check version of library `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`, if it's `4.5.7` or `4.5.8`, try to downgrade to `4.5.6`, as there exist issues for AWS SDK S3. For more details, please take a look at [Amazon S3 Signature Does Not Match - AWS SDK Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625812/signaturedoesnotmatch-in-aws-java-sdk-for-s3/56413603#56413603) and [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7 breaks fetching S3 objects](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919).

Answer (score 0):

The solution we received when we reported a ticket with AWS because all the approaches failed. The scenario is we have our custom AWS KMS encryption enabled for S3 bucket, but we were trying to send "kms key" along with our request when using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest api. AWS said, we don't have to send KMS key, instead send without encrypting from client. When I say unencrypted, it is not exactly that, it is already coming in encrypted form and when we were using "AWSS3V4SinerType" to sign, it was signing an already encrypted file. Hope this makes sense.